# OutOfMemory Exception raised in okHttp onFailure callback

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I am using `Kotlin` and writing a function to upload a file. While testing, I have observed that if I do the following operations, `OutOfMemory` exception is raised and `onFailure` callback is called.

1. Select a file of size 100 MB to upload it to server. Upload it by calling `uploadFile`.
2. While it uploads, disconnect the internet. `onFailure` is called with an exception (`timeout`).
3. Enable the internet again and try to upload it again by calling `uploadFile` function.
4. Repeat the step 2 and 3 for 1-2 more times and app crashes. `onFailure` is called this time with `OutOfMemory` exception.

Here is my code.

```
class UploadManager(
        private val fileTransferDataSource: IListFileTransferDataSource
) {

    private val uploadClient by lazy {
        OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
                .writeTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()
    }

    suspend fun uploadFile(url: String,
                           fileUri: String,
                           downloadUrl: String?,
                           stream: InputStream,
                           callback: ((success: Boolean, filePath: String, url: String?, responseCode: Int?) -> Unit)? = null) {
        val baseUrl = FileTransferUtility.getBaseUrl(url)
        val authToken = fileTransferDataSource.getAuthenticationToken(baseUrl)
        if (baseUrl.isEmpty() || authToken.isEmpty()) {
            stream.close()
            callback?.let { it(false, fileUri, null, null) }
            return
        }

        kotlin.runCatching {
            val buf = ByteArray(stream.available())
            val bytesRead = stream.read(buf)
            stream.close()

            if (bytesRead == -1) {
                callback?.let { it(false, fileUri, null, null) }
                return@runCatching
            }
            val requestBody = create(FileTransferUtility.contentTypeStream.toMediaType(), buf)
            val request = requestBody.let {
                Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .post(it)
                        .addHeader(HttpConstants.Headers.AUTHORIZATION, HttpConstants.Values.AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN_BEARER_FORMAT.format(authToken))
                        .addHeader(HttpConstants.Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, HttpConstants.Values.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .addHeader(HttpConstants.Headers.ACCEPT, HttpConstants.Values.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .build()
            }

            if (request == null) {
                callback?.let { it(false, fileUri, null, null) }
                return@runCatching
            }
            
            uploadClient.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                    call.cancel()
                    callback?.let { it(false, fileUri, null, null) }
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                    response.body?.close()
                    callback?.let { it(response.code == 200, fileUri, downloadUrl, response.code) }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    //Restricting object creation for this class by making it singleton
    companion object : SingletonHolder<UploadManager, IListFileTransferDataSource>(::UploadManager)
}
```

However, it doesn't crash even if I upload multiple files of size 100 MB and they gets upload without any issue. Problem happens only when `onFailure` is triggered multiple times. I am suspecting the some internal buffer aren't getting deallocating on failure.

I have tired the following.

1. Cancelling the dispatcher
2. Add interceptor for Logging with log level `None`.
3. cancelling call explicitly in onFailure callback

Nothing seems to resolve this issue. Please help me to identify the memory leak.

Stack Trace:

```
java.io.IOException: canceled due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 8208 byte allocation with 200 free bytes and 200B until OOM, target footprint 268435456, growth limit 268435456

0 = {StackTraceElement@16551} "okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:515)"
1 = {StackTraceElement@16552} "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)"
2 = {StackTraceElement@16553} "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)"
3 = {StackTraceElement@16554} "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized the problem was with `val buf = ByteArray(inputStream.available())`. It creates a `ByteArray` of huge size in a single go. If we have to upload multiple files of larger size (in my case, 100MB), garbage collector take a while to free the memory from last uploads. It was causing the memory exception. I have changed my code and it stopped being a problem:

```
suspend fun uploadFile(
    url: String,
    fileUri: String,
    downloadUrl: String?,
    stream: InputStream,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope
): Flow<Result> = flow {
    kotlin.runCatching {
        val baseUrl = FileTransferUtility.getBaseUrl(url)
        val authToken = fileTransferDataSource.getAuthenticationToken(baseUrl)

        if (baseUrl.isEmpty() || authToken.isEmpty()) {
            stream.close()
            emit(Result.Failure(fileUri))
            return@flow
        }

        var connection: HttpURLConnection? = null
        val bufferedInputStream = stream.buffered()
        try {
            val fileSize = stream.available()
            if (fileSize == 0)
                throw IOException("Unable to read file $fileUri")

            connection = (URL(url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection).also { conn ->
                addHeadersForUpload(conn, authToken, fileSize)
                conn.readTimeout = UPLOAD_READ_TIMEOUT
            }

            var progress = 0
            emit(Result.InProgress(fileUri, progress))
            BufferedOutputStream(connection.outputStream).use { uploadStream ->
                var bytesWritten = 0
                val buffer = ByteArray(DEFAULT_UPLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE)
                while (true) {
                    val size = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)
                    if (size <= 0)
                        break

                    bytesWritten += size
                    progress = ((100f * bytesWritten) / fileSize).toInt()
                    emit(Result.InProgress(fileUri, progress))
                    uploadStream.write(buffer, 0, size)
                }
                uploadStream.flush()
            }
            val responseCode = connection.responseCode
            val isSuccess = responseCode == 200
            if (isSuccess) {
                if (progress < 100)
                    emit(Result.InProgress(fileUri, 100))
                emit(Result.Success(fileUri, downloadUrl, readResponseBody(connection)))
            } else {
                emit(Result.Failure(fileUri))
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            emit(Result.Failure(fileUri))
        } finally {
            bufferedInputStream.close()
            connection?.disconnect()
        }
    }
}.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)

private fun readResponseBody(connection: HttpURLConnection): String? {
    val builder = StringBuilder()
    val lineBreak = System.getProperty("line.separator")
    BufferedReader(connection.inputStream.reader()).use {
        val line = it.readLine() ?: return@use
        builder.append(line + lineBreak)
    }
    return builder.toString().trim(*lineBreak.toCharArray())
}
```